# Find the Maclaurin series for $\cos^2(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I am given this as a hint:
$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1 + \cos(2x)}{2} \\$

I am not really sure how to start this one, would it just be the regular Maclaurin series squared. For example:

$ (\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-1^nz^(2n)}{2n!})^2$

Thanks for the help !

Comment: The point of the hint is that you take the Maclaurin series for cosine and replace  $ \ x \ $ with $ \ 2x \ $ , add $ \ 1 \ $ to the resulting series, then multiply the entire expression by $ \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ .  You don't square all of that because you have _already used_ the "cosine-squared" identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The maclaurin series for $\cos(2x)$ is
$\cos(2x)=1-2x^2+\frac{2x^4}{3}-\frac{4x^6}{45}....$, can you now follow the comments and use the relation given in the hint?

Answer (score 1):

We have,  $\cos^{2}x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{(2x)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^{4}}{4!}-\frac{(2x)^{6}}{6!}+...)$

Comment: Yes, this begins with following the "hint" given in the Question, but you've not gotten to the Maclaurin series quite yet.